# av_interleaved_write_frame(): Connection reset by peer

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp

When streaming live video to a streaming provider who utilizes FFmpeg, the stream is temporarily stopped, and the encoder logs the following:

```
user.err ffpublish[1:0]: av_interleaved_write_frame(): Connection reset by peer
user.err ffpublish[1:0]: Error writing trailer of rtmp://xxx:1935: Connection reset by peer (-104)
user.info ffpublish[1:0]: Session ended: rtmp://xxx:1935
```

We can replicate the issue by moving from live video from cameras behind a video switcher, to static images from a computer behind the same video switcher.

Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's the question?